# We want to find all characters (other than A) which are followed by triple A

Tags: python, regex

Consider a string s. We want to find all characters (other than A) which are followed by triple A, i.e., have AAA to the right. We don’t want to include the triple A in the output and just want the character immediately preceding AAA . Complete the code given below that would output the required result.

```
def result():
    s = 'ACAABAACAAABACDBADDDFSDDDFFSSSASDAFAAACBAAAFASD'

    result = []
    # compete the pattern below
    pattern = 
    for item in re.finditer(pattern, s):
      # identify the group number below.
      result.append(item.group())
      
    return result
```

I am using the following regex:

```
(.)(AAA)
```

This returns the first C before the first AAA.

But How do I return all the precedent characters in each occurence of AAA?

Comment: So basically `([B-Z])AAA` with `re.findall`? Or are you not actually working with uppercase letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import re

s = 'ACAABAACAAABACDBADDDFSDDDFFSSSASDAFAAACBAAAFASD'

pattern = r"([^A])(?=AAA)"
# compete the pattern below
for item in re.finditer(pattern, s):
  # identify the group number below.
  print(item.group())
```

Result:

```
C
F
B
```

Or, you can simply use `findall`:

```py
print(re.findall(r"([^A])(?=AAA)", s))
```

Result:

```
['C', 'F', 'B']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match B-Z and assert AAA at the right

```
[B-Z](?=AAA)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sPBwmm/1)

```
import re
pattern = r"[B-Z](?=AAA)"
s = "ACAABAACAAABACDBADDDFSDDDFFSSSASDAFAAACBAAAFASD"
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['C', 'F', 'B']
```

Any character except A could be matched using a negated character class

```
[^A](?=AAA)
```